# How can I jump to the error line in Vscode Just like Intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

what should I do to go to the error line just like intellij idea in vscode
[vscode debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16yVS.png)

[idea debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUlte.png)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the View menu
2. Select the Problems menu item
3. Press the Enter key to move to the first problem
4. Press F8 to move to the next problem

Alternatively, the keyboard shortcut is CTRL + SHIFT + M. You might want to look at the official [quick start guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks).

Answer (score 1):

1.[ctrl] + [shift] + m = open error tab

2.up and down arrows to go through the errors

3.[enter] = move focus to place of error